# fast multipole method and geometric algebra

Tags: clifford-algebras, na.numerical-analysis

Hello,

I just learned about fast multipole method(FMM) from this article http://math.nyu.edu/faculty/greengar/shortcourse_fmm.pdf and I really liked the use of complex numbers in 2d. But I didn't like the 3d version, all the phaf with spherical harmonics. So I wandered if it would be possible to use geometric(clifford) algebra to make n-d FMM simple as 2d one. So I would need to somehow embed radial basis function to this geometric algebra and create its Taylor and Laurent expansion.

I have no idea if it would be possible(right now I have very little knowladge about geometric algebra). So I would love to hear some opinions.
And could you please recommend me some good book on Clifford analysis?

Thank you,
Tom